# {margin: 0px auto;} not centering div

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/p1ys5yj3/1/

I trying to center what is dotted in red `.question{ }` to the center of the page with `margin: 0px auto;` but it is not working.

`margin-left:` seems to work but I am not sure why `margin: 0px auto` desn't.

I tried

- `text-align`
- Removing `.question { float: answer;}`
- and `.question { display: block;}`

Comment: You have a `max-width` set on your `content` div of 600px. Your `question` class is centered...you just won't ever see it.

Comment: Unless you want to support older browser, I'd highly recommend using [Flexbox for all of this, it makes things like this much simpler](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 1):

Remove `max-width` from `.content` and add `text-align: center;`. Hope this what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Please modify the CSS in **.content** class by **removing**

> padding:30px auto

and **add**

> margin: 30px auto

then **remove** the

> max-width

from **.question** class and **add**

> width: 100%

I think this should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Update your css with,

```
.content {
 text-align: center;
}
.question {
 text-align: center;
 position: static;
 top: 40px;
 border: 1px dotted red;
 display: inline-block;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 width: 800px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding: 30px;
}
.answer {
 margin: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
}
```